Change background color for cursorline and cursorcolumn

In my vimrc, I have the above configuration. However, the background for lines/columns not currently highlighted is faaar too light, it's extremely jarring and makes it hard for me to focus sometimes.
How can I modify this?

Welcome to Vim! Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest:-)

You can control the background color of the core of the screen by adapting the Normal highlighting group.
To set it to black you could do:
highlight Normal guibg=#000000 ctermbg=0


Not the answer you may want to hear, but: use a different colorscheme.
This is for several reasons which I will explain below.
And don't get me wrong, I like Solarized and I was using it for many years.
I find it aesthetically very pleasing.
It's just a sad fact that it's broken.
Solarized is not what you want
Solarized is famously a low-contrast colorscheme.
Your question is how to add more contrast because the light background color makes it hard for you to see things.
For this reason alone, you should choose a different colorscheme.
One with a little bit more contrast.
Solarized is broken on your machine
Whatever that is on your screenshot, it's not Solarized.
Take a look at the Solarized website and you should quickly note the differences.
You probably forgot to install the terminal palette.
Don't bother to do that now.
Just walk away.
Solarized is broken in general
Solarized is outdated.
Last commit to its Github repo was in 2011.
Vim has evolved a lot over these 13 years.
The general reasons for moving away from Solarized are summarized in more detail in this answer on SO by romainl.
Even if you don't see the cracks in Solarized now, you will.
What to do instead?
Find yourself a different colorscheme.
One you like.
One with the right amount of contrast for you.
There's no objective "best" colorscheme so take some time to look around.
Don't forget to take a look at the default colorschemes that ship with Vim.
They got a full makeover with Vim 9.0.
All of them are good.
Some are great.
See :help new-colorschemes-9.
If you find a colorscheme that's almost right, you can tweak it using an autocommand as explained in :help colorscheme-override.
That's more or less Vivian's answer wrapped in an autocommand:
augroup colorscheme_hacks
  au!
  au ColorScheme <your-colorscheme> hi Normal <whatever>
augroup END

